# Convex hull from cloud of co-ordinates

Tags: geometry, computational-complexity

I'm trying to design an algorithm to find the convex hull of a set of co-ordinates using the slope between two points to determine if a point is part of the convex hull. I'm testing a set of five points:

$$A(135,127),B(444,249),C(441,420),D(275,210),E(383,59)$$

Plotting these points looks like the below:

[image: Scatter plot]

What I first do is find the co-ordinate with the minimum y-value ($E(383,59)$), and then compare the slope of the line between that point and every other point:

$$\begin{align} EA_{slope} &= \frac{59-127}{383-135} = \frac{-68}{248} = -0.24 \\
EB_{slope} &= \frac{59-249}{383-444} = \frac{-190}{-61} = 3.11 \\
EC_{slope} &= \frac{59-420}{383-441} = \frac{-361}{-58} = 6.22 \\
ED_{slope} &= \frac{59-210}{383-275} = \frac{-151}{108} = -1.40 \\
\end{align}$$

I'm looking for the smallest magnitude slope in the negative direction which ends up being $EA$. Using five points was probably a poor idea, but if there were more (so I don't hit the minimum x-value co-ordinate so fast), I'd redo this in the same direction until I find all points in the bottom-left quarter of the hull.

The problems I come upon are that it's very inefficient as I will have to iterate over $n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1$ points ($O(\text{n log n})$?) and I'm not too sure how to go about getting all of the quarters of the hull.

My thought was:

> Smallest magnitude negative slope = point is in bottom-left quarter
>   Biggest magnitude positive slope = point is in the top-left quarter
>   Smallest magnitude positive slope = point is in the top-right quarter
>   Biggest magnitude negative slope = point is in the bottom-right quarter

Is this correct? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a well-traveled topic. You are struggling (it seems) to implement the [Graham scan algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) correctly. This is well-described in a number of locations, some including code. I will cite my own, associated with *Computational Geometry in C*: [link here](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ftp.html).

---

[image: GrahamScan]

          

<sup>(Image from [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/DCG/).)</sup>

---